# Show that the vector path is regular?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $\{\tilde{i}, \tilde{j}, \tilde{k}\}$ be the standard basis of vectors for IR3. If the path $\tilde{x}$ : IR → IR3
is defined by
$$\tilde{x}= \cos 4t\ \tilde{i}+ \sin 4t\ \tilde{j}+ 2t^2\ \tilde{k},$$
then show that $\tilde{x}$ is regular.

I looked online and couldn't find what 'regular' meant in this context. Does it just mean continuous?

Comment: From where did you get the word "regular"? If you got it from a book, which book is?

Comment: highly probable it means that the derivative is non zero

Comment: @janmarqz I think you're right, my friend came to a similar conclusion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From Anthony Tromba and Jerry Mardsen's book, "Vector Calculus," a path c is said to be regular at a point t0 if the derivative of c at t0 does not equal 0. If the derivative of c at t0 does not equal 0 for all t, we say that c is a regular path.